# Custom css properties for IE

Tags: javascript, css

I have a hover effect on some buttons I made using jquery and css, the text that pops up is white text with a black background with text shadows etc. As IE doesnt support this is there a way I can add a IE only rule so it will change the font color if the browser is IE.

```
.social li a strong 
{ 
    font-weight:normal; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:20px; 
    top:-1px; 
    color:#fff; 
    padding:3px; 
    z-index:9999;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); 
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-border-radius:3px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    -webkit-border-radius:3px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    border-radius:3px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe show some code?

Comment: When your question has been answered, click the checkmark under the answer to *accept* it. You don't need to edit your question (adding "SOLVED" or anything like that), just mark the answer accepted (and if you *really* want to, leave a comment saying thanks -- but even that is unnecessary and sometimes discouraged unless you have something more specific to say)

Answer (score 2):

You need to somehow identify IE.

### [1. Use a conditional comments stylesheet.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

This requires an extra HTTP request, but I just call it the *bad browser* tax.

However, you *can* put the extra CSS inline in a `style` element.

### [2. Use a CSS hack](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/06/16/essentials-of-css-hacking-for-internet-explorer/)

This is ugly, and not recommended. For some smallish property settings, it can be useful.

### [3. Attach a hook via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323186/browser-os-as-body-class/4323221#4323221)

This works well, because you can do `.ie #element { ... }`, except, without JavaScript enabled, the user won't see any IE only properties.

Comment: yea but how many users of IE even know what JavaScript is and that there is an option to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional statements 

`If IE do this 

<!--[if IE]> 


Do this

<![endif]-->`

If not IE do this
<!--[if !IE]>-->
Do this     
<!--<![endif]-->

Answer (score 1):

Using internet explorer's conditional comments, you can append a class to your body tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]>  <body class="ie6 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>     <body class="ie7 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>     <body class="ie8 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>     <body class="ie9 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in your stylesheet, you can target the version (or versions) of IE that need additional CSS:

```
.ie .social li a strong { ... }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but I agree that it isn't necessarily pretty. However, when it comes to maintaining CSS, I much prefer writing browser-specific styles without hacks alongside the existing rules.